Replit console window line width getting narrower
In my replit app on Mac (and in the web interface as well), the display area of the console window is shrinks with every line printed in the console. When opening a new console window, it has the usual width (80 chars maybe), and then with every line printed, the line width shrinks down to 2 characters per line.
This started about two days ago (December 6th, 2024). Is this maybe a wrong configuration I have, or is it a bug in replit?
Edit: The lines get shorter when redrawing the window, e.g. when changing the width of the window.


It seems that the issue has been resolved.

In the FastAPI config (e. g. main.py) you can add a middleware handler to get all the exceptions:
@app.middleware("http")
async def log_requests(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        logger.debug(f"Request path: {request.url.path}")
        logger.debug(f"Request method: {request.method}")
        response = await call_next(request)
        logger.debug(f"Response status: {response.status_code}")
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        # Log the error message and stack trace
        logger.error(f"An error occurred while processing the request: {e}", exc_info=True)
        raise  # Re-raise the exception to let FastAPI handle it properly


Here's what i did to get around the issue so i could keep working for now:
import logging


logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,  # Set to DEBUG for more detailed logs
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("agent.log"),  # Logs to a file
        logging.StreamHandler()  # Logs to the console
    ]
)

And you need to adjust how your errors and whatnot are being logged.
